# Windows: Read CMD-Output and bring it to a textbox (Edit) in C++

Tags: c++, console, pipe, cmd

I want to put the output of an cmd-command (e.g. "assoc") into a textbox. I managed this with pipes.

BUT

New lines (\n) on the console aren't shown in the textbox...

So if "assoc" results in

```
.xxx=xxx
.yyy=yyy
.zzz=zzz
```

there is

```
.xxx=xxx.yyy=yyy.zzz=zzz
```

in the textbox

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert LF (\n) char to CR/LF (\r\n) in the output.